# Should we still use ufw in an AWS Lightsail Debian instance since Lightsail has its own firewall?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, amazon-lightsail, ufw

Just signed up for a Lightsail Debian 10 instance on AWS. and set up a new WordPress on it. As an old habit from using DigitalOcean Droplets, I installed ufw to block any connection from ports for other than ssh, http and https.

Later I found the Lightsail console already has an IPv4 Firewall feature, and port 22 and 80 are opened by default.

This makes me wonder, since Lightsail already provides a firewall, does it make sense to do away with ufw? 'Cuz otherwise I'll have to configure both...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that if the AWS security groups are enough for you, then why add another layer of complexity (ufw)? If you want to do more fine-gained filtering, then go for it.